# "Ongoing" or "on-going"

Tags: adjectives, compounds

As per the title, is the proper usage "ongoing" or "on-going" when writing something such as *ongoing research projects*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either is acceptable, though the form `ongoing` is almost uniquely the one used in modern times. (The hyphenated version, as with most compound words in English, was the original form; the hyphen got dropped after time as the word became more common.)as

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ongoing) gives the following origin:

> **ongoing**
>      also on-going, 1877, from on + going (see go).

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://www.future-perfect.co.uk/grammartips/grammar-tip-ongoing.asp) provides some guidance. To quote:

> This word never has been hyphenated,
>   but people think that it is a mix of
>   ‘on’ and ‘going’, but if you think of
>   someone ‘going on about grammar’, you
>   would not say that that person was
>   ‘ongoing’!